# correct a deformed checker texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

So, I'm trying to recreate this setup: [image: youtube video from MobyMotion]

But, when I apply the checker texture, I get this:
[image]

The texture if really deformed.
How can I correct this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to uniformly add texture to a complex mesh without using UV mapping?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52938/is-there-a-way-to-uniformly-add-texture-to-a-complex-mesh-without-using-uv-mappi)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that doesn't really help me..

Comment: object coordinates. simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your coordinates to object.

And make sure that you apply the scale to your object.

(<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in Object mode)

[image]

read:

[Non-Uniform Scaling during UV unwrap. What is this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/non-uniform-scaling-during-uv-unwrap-what-is-this)

and

[Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298)

and

[Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318)